# Using getter with Qt Gui

Tags: c++, qt, getter

I making a game. When an user presses A there is an attack and program returns true. It works. But I wanted to create a getter that returns the value of this boolean, and here is the break:
it doesn't work. 
When I use the getter I created in my controller by doing:

```
item= new item();

if(item->getAttack()){

 //do my stuff
}
```

it doesn't return anything when I press A. Why?

This is my file.cpp (`attack_` a is private variable)

```
void item::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){

    switch(event->key()){

    case Qt::Key_A:
        attack_=true;
        break;
    }

    attack();
    update();
 }

void item::attack(){

    if(attack_){

        qDebug()<<attack_;//return me true every time I press A
        qDebug()<<"I am going to kill you!!";
    }
}

bool item::getAttack()// Doesn't work
{
    return attack_;
}


class item: public Element, public QGraphicsPixmapItem{

public:
item(): Element(0,0){

        attack_=false;
        attack();
        getAttack();
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    }
}
```

Comment: What means `it doesn't return anything`? Your `item::getAttack()` function should always return something, otherwise your code will not compile. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Where is `if(item->getAttack())` called?

Comment: I put a qDebug()<< attack_m; in my getter and removed the one that was in my function attack() and when I call getAttack in my controller it still display my "I am going to kill you" but not the the value of my boolean attack_ anymore!

Comment: I call if(item->getAttack()) in my controller.cpp

Comment: @Ary Yes, but where? Right after you construct your item? Or do you listen to key events in your controller and call it there?

Comment: I listen my key events in my item class not in my controller.Then I construct an item in my controller.cpp and call my getAttack().

Comment: @Ary So it should return the default value. What does pressing A have to do with it?

Comment: In fact When I press A I set my attack_ at true and when A is released I set it at false. Normally When I press A an image appears but I didn't want to create this new Object from an other class in my item class, so I wanted to returns the value of this boolean and test if it is true set the image in my scene in my controller! Moreover, I removed attack_m= false in my item constructor so there is no default value anymore.

Comment: I still don't understand what does pressing A have to do with calling `item->getAttack()` in the controller. Try calling `item::getAttack()` in the `item::attack()` function. You'll see that it works just fine.

Comment: Yes it works fine if I do as you told me! But I wanted to know when an attack is emitted and then display a weapon for example! That's why I put it in the controller! I checked is value when I call it in my controller and it is always false. Maybe my logic is just wrong.

Comment: You have a few options here. You can move the key press handling inside the controller, or you can emit a signal in your `Item` class to tell the controller that an attack has been performed. Note that to use signals your class must inherit `QObject`.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to think about :)